# How could I resize input-group?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a `jumbotron` and trying to put an `input-group` form to make searches on my website. The problem is when I add the `form` with `input` and `button` and try to resize the form to 100% it doesn't stick together and the `input text` doesn't resize.

How could I fix this problem ?

trying

```
<div class="jumbotron"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="img-responsive" style="margin:-50px 0 -20px 20px;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"><img src="~/Imagens/logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("view", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" })){
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What do you looking for ?">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--jumbotron-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some custom CSS on your page?
maybe this code can be the problem..

take a look:

```
<div class="jumbotron"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What do you looking for ?">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/AlvaroAlves/0jrkhuy0/

Comment: or try tro put a class on your input like:
`<input type="text" class="form-control full-with" placeholder="What do you looking for ?">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
                </div>`

and in your css put:

`.full-width {
  width: 100% !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Your Bootstrap code works fine, check this [pen](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/WEzqNQ).

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What do you looking for ?">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Most probably some CSS code is interfering with Bootstrap's CSS.